# How to query deleted items only if they have related value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to ask help with a query. Below are my tables.  I wanted to query all post that are not deleted and include deleted post if they have a transaction record.

**Posts Table**

| id | caption | price | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor | 9.99 | 2023-03-30 01:20:11 |
| 2 | Collaboratively leverage existing. | 4.21 |  |

**Transactions Table**

| id | post_id | user_id | charge_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3239 | ch_12345abcde | 2023-03-30 01:20:11 |

Expected query result will include both posts since the deleted post has a transaction.

Comment: What value does the deleted_at column get if the post was not deleted?

Comment: Using Laravel  ?

Comment: @AbbasBagheri Most likely `NULL`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple `LEFT JOIN` with where clause to filter post with no deletion date and such having a record in the transaction table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts P
LEFT JOIN Transactions T
    ON P.id = T.post_id
WHERE P.deleted_at IS NULL
    OR  T.id IS NOT NULL
```